# JSOUP: Get text after div with specific text inside

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

In short, I am creating an Ancient Greek concordance program for OSX, so I need to collect definitions from a lexicon.

In the http://biblehub.com/greek/1.htm page, I need to retrieve the text under "Strong's Exhaustive Concordance". The issue is that that div in the HTML file contains the same class as other divs, which makes programmatically finding that specific div difficult.

In JSOUP, I searched for text after the divs that contain "Strong's Exhaustive Concordance," yet the output is "Strong's Exhaustive Concordance" instead of the definition of the word.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Greek {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://biblehub.com/greek/1.htm").get();

        Elements n = doc.select("div.vheading2:containsOwn(Strong's Exhaustive Concordance) + p");

        System.out.println(n.text());
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the output to be "Of Hebrew origin..."?

Comment: @TDG Yes, that would be to goal.

Comment: @TDG Yes, that would be the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that there is a very handy tool that will help you locate the element in Chrome dev tool?

Right click on the element you want to locate, then right-click -> Inspect, which will present you with the HTML code for the element. Right-click on the element and select Copy -> You will see a range of options such as CSS Selector, XPath available for you :) See below screenshot:

So in your case, it would be:
    `Jsoup.select("#leftbox > div > p:nth-child(74)");`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, and your answer seems to this particular instance; however, the index of the definition will not always be 74 with other words. Is there anyway that I can find an element in HTML that contains a certain String, and then print the subsequent <p>, which should be the definition? Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

I've ferreted the solution.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Greek {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://biblehub.com/greek/1.htm").get();


        // contains an array of all elements with out desired ID
        Elements n = doc.select("div.vheading2");

        // cycle through the array until we find the member that contains the text above the word's definition
        for (Element e : n) {
            if (e.text().equalsIgnoreCase("Strong's Exhaustive Concordance")) {

                // finally, we print the next element, which is our definition
                System.out.println(e.nextElementSibling().text());
            }
        }
    }
}
```